# Sending commands from a windows laptop to micropython ev3 using Python

Tags: python-3.x, lego-mindstorms-ev3

I am currently got a Python (3.8) script running on a Windows laptop which creates a GUI using TKinter. I would like for this script to send commands to the EV3 (possibly running a second script). For example, if I click a forward button on the TKinter GUI the EV3 drives forward. The EV3 is loaded with Lego's micropython for the EV3. I am okay with using the standard "EV3Dev" if that is the easier option.

I can work both the TKinter GUI and the EV3 fine individually, the issue occurs when I try and combine them. In other words, I am looking for a way for the EV3 to receive commands from the laptop and act on them. Help would be appreciated.

Comment: "any suggestions" is a bit too vague for stackoverflow. It's not clear what kind of help you need. For example, do you know how to use python to send commands without tkinter - is the problem with sending commands? Or, do you know how to send commands, but don't know how to hook that code up to a button?

Comment: @BryanOakley I have updated the post. The problem is with sending/receiving commands. Sorry for the lack of clarity

Comment: _"The problem is with sending/receiving command"_ - what is the problem? Are you getting errors? I suggest you start with a [mcve] that sends a single command without using tkinter. Get that working first, and then ask about how to integrate it with tkinter.

Comment: @BryanOakley I have not yet attempted to integrate the GUI. This will be the next step and should be straightforward. I do not know how to send the messages to the EV3 from Python. I have looked at the Lego and ev3dev documentation however I could not find a way to do this.

Comment: The title specifically mentions tkinter, and it includes the tkinter tag. If you don't really need the tkinter help just yet you should edit the title and remove the tag.